# WSUS putting Internet Explorer 9 update into "Optional updates."

Tags: deployment, wsus, internet-explorer-9, system-center-essentials

I can't seem to find anyone else with this issue, but I'm deploying Internet Explorer 9 via WSUS to my clients. Some of them accept it and install it as a normal update but randomly others get it in the "optional updates" section and never install it.

I can't seem to find a way in WSUS tom make it non-optional.Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer to this. Selecting add this to add/remove programs causes this.